# Need help to finding pattern

Tags: sql, regex, sql-server-2008, patindex, charindex

I need to find the pattern like following ...

I have one column named Solution, In that user typed information will be captured. Some where in that column user entering his id. Id will be like ,

USER123456 
USER456123

Pattern : ID always starts with 'USER' , and next 6 digits will be numeric

So ID can be any where in the string. Based on the pattern I need to extract the id.

I want achieve like ,

%USER[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%

### Example Text :

---

**USERID: USER525511    I will be Expiring on 26-Jun-2014**

From the above I want to extract

**USER525511**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select substring(col,
                 patindex('%[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', col),
                 10)
```

Comment: Almost yes but I want to freeze the first four digits

which means I need to hard code the first four digits...

%USER[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%

Comment: @vignesh . . . Then change the patter to start with `'user'`.

Comment: USER123458
use123458

Try this values